# How to find substring in an array in c#?

Tags: c#

Our employees numbers built in hierarchy all in a TreeView

I want to highlight some employees and all employees under that employee

Example

Employee ID

```
A1 CEO
   A12 CIO
     A12.1  Software Manager
         A12.11  Java Developer
         A12.12  .Net Developer
         A12.13  Python Developer
     A12.2  Data Manager
         A12.21  Data Analyst
         A12.22  Data Scientist
   A22 CFO
     A22.1  Accounting Manager
         A22.11  Accountant
         A22.12  Auditor
```

A list of employees will be sent as string

```
"A12.11,A12.2,A22"
```

In this case All employees under A12.2 should be highlighted too
and all employees under A22 should be highlighted too

So these employees should be highlighted

```
A12.11
A12.2
A12.21
A12.22
A22
A22.1
A22.11
A22.12
```

I built this code to select all employees, but it only highlights the exact employee and not the employees under them

```
       foreach (TreeNode tn in nodes)
        {
            if (EmpSelect.Split(',').Contains(tn.Name))
            {
                tn.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Any idea how to make this code highlights all emplyees and employees under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the microsoft documentation for [How to: Iterate Through All Nodes of a Windows Forms TreeView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-iterate-through-all-nodes-of-a-windows-forms-treeview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), you'll see an easy way to recursively modify all nodes under a single node.

Here's a modified example for your question:

```
private void SetColorOnNodeAndSubNodes(TreeNode treeNode, Color color)
{
    // Color this node
    treeNode.ForeColor = color;

    // Color its children 
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        SetColorOnNodeAndSubNodes(childNode, color);
    }
}
```

Then in your sample code you would do something like:

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in nodes)
{
    if (EmpSelect.Split(',').Contains(tn.Name))
    {
        SetColorOnNodeAndSubNodes(tn, Color.Red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to check all child tree nodes recursively. You can make use from it by rewriting to highlighting.

```
    // Updates all child tree nodes recursively.
private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
{
   foreach(TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
   {
      node.Checked = nodeChecked;
      if(node.Nodes.Count > 0)
      {
         // If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively.
         this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not looking to find checked ones. but I am looking to identify the child in treeview

Comment: this issue is array related not treeview